# What is this seed pod?

Tags: spices, indian-cuisine, food-identification, ingredients

Every now and then I come across this seed pod when I order Baingan Bharta (aka Punjabi Eggplant) from my favorite Indian restaurant.  They're roughly 2cm (3/4 inch) long and about as thick as a wooden pencil. The taste is strong and earthy and rather savory to my palate.  The pod has three folds, for lack of a better word, and the seeds are smaller than okra/gumbo but have similar texture.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: Here they are in action: https://youtu.be/9biIOtEYeHc?t=76

Comment: There are also larger black cardamom seed pods which are used in the same way in South Asian dishes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like [cardamom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardamom) to me, regularly used in Indian and other South Asian cuisine and often left as whole seed pods in dishes for unsuspecting diners to accidentally chew on.

Comment: That's right, either push them to the side of the plate or eat them but if the latter don't chew too much  - too much flavour and they get stuck in your teeth.

Comment: They’re guaranteed to be in the very last mouthful;)

Comment: @ChrisH 'too much flavour' is entirely subjective, as the degree to which they stick in teeth is heavily dependent on one's dentition. ;-)

Comment: @Spagirl indeed, my light squeeze would be too much for many people, and I do leave some on the plate, but overall like them.  Others I know would eject a pod they'd accidentally eaten, and perhaps you might enjoy them more than me.

Comment: The spice is also popular in baked goods in Scandinavia.  In such recipes, the dark seeds are removed from the pods and ground before adding them to a dough or filling.

Comment: I have a Palestinian friend who chew them like people chew tobacco. He'd just idly plop a couple in his mouth every so often. I have no idea how he can stand it. To each his own I guess.

Comment: @slebetman I bet people would say that about coffee beans too.  And in parts of the Middle east, cardamom coffee is popular.  It's very nice, but hard to get a light enough roast coffee in the UK.

Comment: Also elevates rice to unexpected new heights. Main ingredient in Bryani  spice.

Comment: @ChrisH cardamom milkshake made from cardamom syrup is also a great treat.

Comment: Cardamom is also the world's 3rd most expensive spice. Only being beat by vanilla pods and saffron.

Comment: @NeilMeyer I'll have to try that (not that I'm much of a milkshake drinker). Searching for that also suggested various hot drinks with milk, with or without chocolate